# How to post 2D array to .net mvc controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, asp.net-mvc, json

Here is my js code on the page:

```
var data = [
  ["Benz", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

$.ajax({
     url: "/Home/SaveData",
     type: "POST",
     contentType: 'application/json',
     data:JSON.stringify({ data: data }),,
     dataType: 'json',
});
```

Here is my mvc action given below:

```
[HttpPost]
public string save(string[][] data)
```

Null value was posted, However, I tried to use `List< string>`  instead of `string[][]` , the hold string of array collected as an item of the list (not a row to a list item).

How to bind this 2D array at server side?

Comment: Try **List<string[]>** or **List<List<string>>** instead.

Comment: Check this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax don't do stringify, Just try putting as data itself,

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/Home/SaveData",
 type: "POST",
 contentType: 'application/json',
 data: { data: data },
 dataType: 'json',
});
```

If you want to stringify it, You need to override the default model binder refer [this CustomModelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779885/mvc4-json-model-binding-doesnt-work/23781392#23781392) for overriding the model binder.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below

```
var data = [
 ["Benz", "Kia", "Nissan", "Toyota", "Honda"],
 ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
 ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
 ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
 ];

$.ajax({
 url: "/Home/SaveData",
 type: "POST",
 contentType: 'application/json',
 data:{ data: data },
 dataType: 'json',
});
```

Now the data can be binded at the server side.